# Why isn't the Vue custom and non-custom prop validators working on this?

Tags: validation, vue.js, components

I have two Vue components here and everything is writing out fine to the page.  The only issue is the props validator.  It doesn't seem to be looking at the arrays and filtering out the ones that have numbers in them and that aren't equal to four items.  It's just printing out everything to the page.  What is wrong with this code?  Thanks for any help that can be given!

I've looked up Vue documentation and YouTube videos but it seems like I've already done what is suggested.  I'm following what they have so it seems I'm missing something no how the value gets passed to the prop?  Not sure.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div id="app">    
        <course :menu="menu1"></course>
        <course :menu="menu2"></course>
</div>
```

Here's the VUE code I have:

```
Vue.component("dish",{
    template: `
        <p>{{food}} &lt; - Delicious!</p>
    `,
    props:["food"]   
})

Vue.component("course",{
    template:  `
        <section class="course">
            <dish v-for="f in menu" :food="f"></dish>
        </section>
    `,
    props: {
        menu:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            validator(foodArray){
                return foodArray.every(food=>typeof food === "string") && foodArray.length === 4  
                //PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE RIGHT HERE ABOVE THIS ISN'T VALIDATING
            }
        }
    }
})
new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
        menu1:["apple","pear","lemon",22],
        menu2:["hamburger", "fries", "shake", "soda","poop"]
    }
})
```

Comment: validators won't filter anything out. they'll simply log an error if the function returns false. are you not seeing the errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No, I'm not seeing it in the console.  Not seeing anything which is messing with me a bit.  So the validators actually don't change the output, they are mainly for output in the console?

Comment: Right. Validators just validate the input data and if they find it to be invalid they throw an error.

Comment: any idea then why these validators aren't working?  Nothing is showing up in the console.  Nothing is working at all.  Thanks so far for your help!

Comment: Here's [a fiddle with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/513suagr/). You can see in the console an "invalid prop" warning that the "menu" prop is expecting a String and received an Array. If you change the `type: String` to `type: Array`, you'll then see a "custom validator check failed" warning.